# Вывод записей на любой странице шорткодом Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Появилась необходимость сделать шорткод, который выводит записи на любой странице блога. Ранее использовал стандартный цикл в `index.php` и все выводилось корректно. Для реализации шорткода прописал в функции тот же код:

```
    add_shortcode('shop-code', 'my_shortcode_function');
    function my_shortcode_function() {
     if ( have_posts() ) : 
            // Start the loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            // End the loop.
            endwhile;



        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        else :
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;

}
```

В `content.php` реализовал вывод записи в нужном мне виде. Когда вставляю шорткод на нужную страницу, он начинает бесконечно просто повторять содержимое страницы, записи не выводит. Подскажите **как изменить код шорткода**, чтобы заработало?

Comment: Зачем вам тут шорткод?)

Answer (score 2):

```
the_post()
have_posts()
```

Работают внутри цикла. Вы забыли указать, какие посты выводить. Задайте свой цикл. Например, даный запрос будет выводить 10 последних постов из категории новости:

```
function my_shortcode_function() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => 'news'
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
        // Start the loop.
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            // End the loop.
        endwhile;
    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    }
```